# Will all effects be executed if one of them redirects to external URL?

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I have a case where clicking a button dispatches some action.
This action is being listened to by two effects:

```
sendAnalytics$ = createEffect(
  () =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(MyActions.ButtonClicked),
      tap(() => {
        this.analyticsSerice.send({timestamp: new Date()})
      })
    ),
  { dispatch: false }
);

navigateToNextStep$ = createEffect(
  () =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(MyActions.ButtonClicked),
      tap(() => {
        window.location.href = "https://next-step.com"
      })
    ),
  { dispatch: false }
);
```

As you can see, the first one just sends some event. The other one though, navigates to another webpage. I think it's a potential race condition, but I'm not sure, knowing that JS runs in a single thread. Does the order of effects creation have any impact on that?

I'd like the analytics event to always be sent, before the user is taken away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The effects are executed in the order that they're registered.
But, that doesn't make sure that the analytics has been send (depending on the implementation).
If the request takes a while, it might get canceled when navigating away from the page.

Comment: What if in my example, the invocation of `this.analyticsSerice.send` was awaited? Does it change anything?

Comment: That doesn't change it. The effects will be invoked one by one, but it doesn't await a result.

Comment: Alright, do you have any recommendation on how to make it so that the analytics are guaranteed  to be sent (aside from network errors obviously)? I do not want to merge these two effects into one, since sending analytics event and moving to another step in the process (by redirecting) are two separate processes.

Comment: The analytics effect can dispatch a "AnalyticsSendSuccesfully" action that is used to trigger the navigation effect.